# numpy 2D array - choose all values from 1st column having max value in 2nd column

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

Given a numpy 2D array, I want to **randomly select a value from the 1st column whose 2nd column value is maximal**.  I found this to be quite straightforward when there was only one maximum value in the 2nd column, but I need to be able to handle multiple maxima.

In the array shown below, the max value in the 2nd column = 6, and there are 4 instances of this.  So, I want to randomly select one of these 1st column values (ie: 4, 1, -5, or -3).

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[ 4,6],
                [-7,4],
                [ 1,6],
                [-5,6],
                [ 0,4],
                [-4,2],
                [ 7,5],
                [-3,6],
                [ 0,3]])
```

The following line work perfectly, but I'm wondering if a more experienced coder could **simplify** it at all:

```
r = np.random.choice(arr[np.where(arr[:,1] == np.max(arr[:,1]))][:,0])
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `r = np.random.choice(arr[(arr[:,1] == arr[:,1].max())][:,0])`

numpy arrays have a method for max, and instead of 'where' you can just set the equality as your index.

Comment: Thanks - simpler &  faster!